# What is the shortest translation for "Auto Saved" in Portuguese?

Tags: uso-de-palavras, tradução-inglês, palavra-para-ideia

The way this example below is proposed is indeed exactly as it appears in the menu option. So I am trying to come up with a shorter version for it instead of using:

> Salvo Automáticamente

Comment: Guardado Automaticamente. Portugues-PT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Salvo automaticamente* is the phrase you commonly find on the web, but if you want a shorter one the obvious choice is ***autossalvo***, with corresponding verb *autossalvar* and noun *autossalvamento*. I found a couple of *auto salvos* and *auto-salvos* on the web, but they are very rare. For instance there is this [emacs tutorial in GitHub, 2014](https://github.com/jwiegley/emacs-release/blob/master/etc/tutorials/TUTORIAL.pt_BR) (my emphasis in all quotes):

> SALVAMENTO AUTOMÁTICO
>
> Quando você fizer mudanças em um arquivo, mas você ainda não tiver salvo, elas podem ser perdidas se o seu computador der algum problema. Para proteger você disso, o Emacs periodicamente escreve um **arquivo "auto salvo"** para cada arquivo que você estiver […] Quando você salvar o arquivo da maneira normal, o Emacs removerá os **arquivos auto salvos**.

Or this thread on [“Chio, Bateria e Instalação” in HTForum (2013):](http://www.htforum.com/forum/threads/chio-bateria-e-instalacao.209262/)

> Em relação a sua resposta que o chrome crashou, o forum tem um **Auto-Salvo**, só não sei aonde salva... mas toda hora está salvando a resposta para, caso aconteça isso ai...

With the 1990 Acordo Ortográfico rules the correct spelling is *autossalvo*; if you prefer the previous rules then it would be *auto-salvo*, like [*auto-suficiente*, which now is *autossuficiente* (Priberam)](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/autossuficiente). *Autossalvar* and *autossalvamento*, correctly spelled, are easier to find. For instance, *autossalvar* at [Prefeitura Municipal de Içara (2014):](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&espv=2&q=%22O%20Word%20pode%20autossalvar%20o%20documento%20a%20cada%20X%20minutos%22&oq=%22O%20Word%20pode%20autossalvar%20o%20documento%20a%20cada%20X%20minutos%22&gs_l=serp.3..30i10k1.9837.12298.0.12703.2.2.0.0.0.0.186.275.1j1.2.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.2.273.YphFlRLwFhA)

> O Word pode **autossalvar** o documento a cada X minutos conforme configuração desta opção pelo usuário.

Or *autossalvamento* in this 2013 book, [*Microsoft Project 2013* by Ricardo Vargas and Allan Christian Rocha:](https://books.google.pt/books?id=ZrBKAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA44&lpg=PA44&dq=autossalvamento&source=bl&ots=e0ArGRsdZA&sig=crxdNUdwYDSA6Hi4COMWkNwC160&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwit7uSe0-XRAhUBzRQKHTCxDxsQ6AEIOTAE#v=onepage&q=autossalvamento&f=false)

> **7.4 Autossalvamento**
>
> O Microsoft Project também permite que se possa salvar automaticamente um arquivo de projeto em intervalos predefinidos.
>
> […]
>
> Para configurar as opções de **autossalvamento**:
>   1. Acesse a guia ***Arquivo*** (***Backstge***) e clique em ***Opções***; […]

Now, you don’t find this words in any dictionary. But that’s the way language and dictionaries work: editors wait for words to gain some currency before including them in their dictionaries.

Comment: Funnily enough, both VOP and VCLP list a few options for things that are automatically destroyed, but none for things that are automatically preserved.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jacinto! This really helped me out. I went ahead and utilized "Auto Salvo"!